# Converting power point (ppt) file to image

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I am currently trying to automate a way to convert a powerpoint slide to an image that I can then use within my application.  I have the method down using the powerpoint addin:

```
Private Function convert_slide(ByVal targetfile As String, ByVal imagepath As String, ByVal slide_index As Integer)
    Dim pptapplication As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
    Dim prsPres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation = pptapplication.Presentations.Open(targetFile, True, False, False)
    prsPres.Slides(slide_index).Export(imagepath, "jpg", 0, 0)
    prsPres.Close()
    pptapplication.Quit()


    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(prsPres)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptapplication)

    Return Image.FromFile(imagepath)

End Function
```

Now this works for one file but if I try to run the function again it says that the destination path is in use. It seems that power point is locking the file. I don't want to change file names each time it runs. I would like to reuse that temp file each time.  Any ideas how to make it so the file doesn't get locked?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a Com object. You need to dispose it.

```
Private Function convert_slide(ByVal targetfile As String, ByVal imagepath As String, ByVal slide_index As Integer) As Image
  Dim pptapplication As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
  Dim prsPres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation = pptapplication.Presentations.Open(targetFile, True, False, False)
  prsPres.Slides(slide_index).Export(imagepath, "jpg", 0, 0)
  prsPres.Close()
  pptapplication.Quit()
  Microsoft.Office.InteropMarshal.FinalReleaseComObject(prsPres)
  Microsoft.Office.InteropMarshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptapplication) 
  Return Image.FromFile(imagepath)

End Function
```

Comment: I added the displosing lines but still the same problem. I updated my question to reflect that now.

Comment: Does the application variable have an Exit/Quit method? If so call it before disposing.

Comment: I called    pptapplication.Quit() but still same locked file error.

Comment: That usually works for all the other Com objects I have used. By sure your first instance is closed by the task manager before trying it again. It may still be locked from earlier.

Comment: @EricF, did you try my last suggestion?

Comment: I did check and powerpoint.exe does close before the next instance starts but even with it closed, the error still appears. Something else is holding onto the image file.

Comment: May be something with the image. Sorry I couldn't fix it for you.